# Regex match everything after parenthesis

Tags: regex, file

I am trying to bulk rename around 10,000 files. I have a tool which can use Regex to do this.

I simply need a regex matching `" ("` and everything after that (space, parenthesis, everything).

Anyone able to help with this really simple problem real fast?

Comment: This seems pretty trivial. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: (.*        and a few others, however I don't have hardly any regex experience, I think the program is attempting to read the ( as a regex term, not as an actual letter

Comment: it might be a problem with the program I am using then, as both answers at this time show to match the entire phrase.

Comment: Could you tell us what tool you are using?

Comment: Bulk File Rename Utility - I ended up just using a setting to trim everything after the first (, then run a second time to delete the last 2 characters.

Comment: @NRGdallas The entire phrase = even what's before ' ('? Then it seems like a limitation of the tool you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are meta-characters in regex, i.e. they mean something special. If you want to signify a literal character that happens to be a meta-character, you need to escape it using a backslash (`\`). For example, consider the caret (`^`), which is a meta-character that matches the beginning of a string.

```
^abcd
matches strings beginning with the sequence of characters "abcd"

\^abcd
matches the sequence of characters "^abcd"
```

You can read up on the difference between special and literal characters in regexen and how to escape them here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 9):

If you want the open parantheses included in the match:

```
/ \(.*/
```

If not, use a positive lookbehind:

```
/(?<= \().*/
```

See it in action here:
http://regexr.com?32p42

Comment: The delimiters are not part of the regex but only an artefact used by specific regex engines/languages.

Comment: @m.buettner javascript and PCRE (and perl) all use delimiters. Still worth noting it's just a delimiter.

Comment: @JanDvorak sure they do. and .NET, Java and most tools don't (and the OP is using a tool)

Comment: Lookbehind is not universally supported. Some flavors don't support _any_ lookbehind.

Comment: Yes, the / are just delimiters. I always include them for readability, but they may or may not be required.

Comment: @Jarmund I agree on the use of delimiters, but they still should be noted as such.

Answer (score 5):

You should really check out [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), since this is probably the easiest thing you can do with regex. This should do:

```
[ ]\(.*
```

The square brackets are just to visualize the space. They can (but don't have to) be omitted.